# How to match forward head and reply head in email under the multi-lingual context

Tags: email-parsing

In email content processing, different mail clients send different re and fw heads, see below.

I need to recognise this heads in order to separate mail contents for the sake of saving and displaying. Apart from hard-coding all these heads, is there any other way out?

[image]

[image]